# Mongodb change enterprise edition to community edition

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb is in version 3.0 and run on Linux Redhat 6. 
I do not use entreprise options, then I would like to switch enterprise edition to community edition. Any drawback on data? It's much like binary upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using an Enterprise storage engine (eg. [Encrypted Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) in MongoDB 3.2+), the data format in MongoDB Community and Enterprise editions is identical and changing between editions is just a change in the MongoDB server binaries. If you need to change storage engines you can do so without downtime on replica sets using a rolling maintenance procedure (see: [Your Ultimate Guide to Rolling Upgrades](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/your-ultimate-guide-to-rolling-upgrades)).

I would recommend using matching release versions when changing between MongoDB Enterprise and Community editions to minimize any unexpected issues. The standard upgrade/compatibility caveats (as mentioned in the [MongoDB Release Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/)) apply if you happen to be upgrading or downgrading between major MongoDB versions (i.e. 3.2 and 3.4).